# Google sheet conditional formatting and lock cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to do formula like:

if E2 cell is "Yes" then F2 I locked for editing

if E2 is "No"  then G2 is locked for editing

is any way to do this in Google sheet?

Comment: This might have an answer for this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620299/google-script-lock-cells