# Google Sheets - Locking Cells after value reached and one other thing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Making a self-scheduling spreadsheet for my co-workers.  The goal is for them to put their hours (12 or 6) in the cell that corresponds with the date and their name.  I am trying to have it so that a date column will lockout after the sum cell for that column reaches a certain total.

I am using this ([Google Script Lock Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620299/google-script-lock-cells)) as my basis but I am not having much luck.

```
    function myFunction() {
  function onOpen() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var cell = source.getRange("B12").getValue();
  var range = ss.getRange("B2:B11");

  if (cell == 10) {

    // Protect range B2:B11 if cell 'B12' = 10
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    Logger.log

  } else {

    // Remove protection if cell 'B12' is anything other than 10
    var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      var protection = protections[i];
      protection.remove();
    }
  }  
} 
}
```

I am also looking to have the sum represent shits rather than hours so if a person wrote "12" the sum column would record "1"

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You should change several things

1. Do not nest `onOpen` inside `myFunction` - it will not work
2. If you want the protections to be update on every update of `B12` - you should use the `onEdit` trigger instead of `onOpen`
3. It is better to replace `cell == 10` through `cell >= 10` to account for the possibility that the value accidentally trespasses the maximum
   4.It is not enough to create a protection, to make it useful you need to [remove editors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) from it
4. Only the [owner of the script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser) (you) should maintain access
5. For this, use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead of a simple one, to make sure that it runs always as you and not the user that opens the document

**Sample (to be [bound to an installable onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)):**

```
function bindAnOnEditTiggerToMe() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var cell = source.getRange("B12").getValue();
  var range = ss.getRange("B2:B11");

  if (cell >= 10) {    
    // Protect range B2:B11 if cell 'B12' = 10
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    protection.addEditor(me);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }    
  } else {    
    // Remove protection if cell 'B12' is anything other than 10
    var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);    
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      var protection = protections[i];
      protection.remove();
    }
  }  
}
```