# How to lock a cell on certain condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I know I can use data validation to prevent anonymous users from input in certain cell, however, is there any way that I can prevent people from edit the value they input already?

For example:

When anonymous users input the price below, then manager will check the price and click the checkbox.

| Price | Confirm |
| --- | --- |
| 45743 | 口 |

Is there any way to lock the price cell, prevent it from editing or deleting whenever the checkbox is clicked?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) trigger to change it back to oldValue on every edit or you can take a look at [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Script Lock Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620299/google-script-lock-cells)

Comment: Are you familiar with `protection` [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect)